# Apache Nutch SolrIndexer error in SolrCloud mode

Tags: java, solr, nutch, solrcloud, nutch2

I have configured Apache Nutch 2.3.1 and crawled few websites. I have to index these documents to Solr (6.6.3) that is running in Cloud mode. When I execute solrindex command, I got following exception

```
2018-05-02 13:10:40,679 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Ignoring exception during close for org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector@3bd3d05e
java.io.IOException: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Server refused connection at: http://10.11.22.156:8983/solr/collection2
    at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.close(SolrIndexWriter.java:103)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.close(IndexWriters.java:114)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.close(IndexerOutputFormat.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:670)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.closeQuietly(MapTask.java:2019)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:797)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1754)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Server refused connection at: http://10.11.22.156:8983/solr/collection2
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.executeMethod(HttpSolrServer.java:559)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:210)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:206)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:124)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:68)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:54)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.close(SolrIndexWriter.java:97)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.11.22.156:8983 refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.executeMethod(HttpSolrServer.java:448)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
```

Where is the problem? If I repeat the same job with solr without cloud mode, it works fines.

Comment: Does the URL referenced work from the server doing the indexing? (I.e. can you access `http://10.11.22.156:8983/solr/collection2` from the server?)

Comment: Yes I can access it i.e., its admin dashboard is accessible without any issue

Comment: -- from the server running Nutch, and using the exact same host? Does `curl http://10.11.22.156:8983/solr/collection2` work?

Comment: i also stuck in the same place. Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 4):

The error straight forward showing that **you have an Apache Nutch server, which is unable to access this particular node and port of Apache Solr** http://10.11.22.156:8983/solr/collection2.

**You need access between these two servers to make them communicate with each other :**

1. You need to provide outbound permission to solr server to do request response with Apache Nutch server.
2. Also, you need to provide inbound permission to Apache Nutch server to access the given solr IP and port.